# How to set up Coinpayments IPN in Nextjs 13 directory?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, coinpayments

I have a Nextjs 13 app using app directory, and I'm trying to get [Coinpayments IPN](https://github.com/OrahKokos/coinpayments-ipn) configured for it.

Their documentation says to set up a file which you upload to your server to recieve the payments, which looks like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {String} hmac
 * @param {String} ipnSecret
 * @param {Object} payload
 * @returns {Boolean}
 * @throws {CoinpaymentsIPNError}
 */
const { verify } = require('coinpayments-ipn');
const CoinpaymentsIPNError = require('coinpayments-ipn/lib/error');

let isValid, error;

try {
  isValid = verify(hmac, ipnSecret, payload);
} catch (e) {
  error = e;
}
if (error) {
  if (error instanceof CoinpaymentsIPNError) {
    // handle invalid payload
  }
  // make bug report
}

if (isValid) {
  // valid
} else {
  // invalid
}
```

Now I've tried to adapt this to a Next JS server component, but to no avail. What I'm trying to do now is inside my `app/api/ipn.ts` is return the body of the request e.g:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req:any) {

  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Must be POST" },
      {
        status: 405,
      })
  }

  console.log('Received raw payload:', req);
  
}
```

But on Vercel, as with any combinination of code I try, I get the exact same error message:

```
IPN Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6662:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6636:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1236:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

What am I doing wrong here? In the Coinpayments dashboard I see the IPNs being sent but never recieved.

So **I think** that the IPN is correctly being uploaded to my server on Vercel but for some reason it's not able to read the incoming requests?

Please help!